# Moving IMG Elements To Beginning Of Document With Only CSS

Tags: css

I have many post documents like this:

```
<p>...</p>
<img/>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<img/>
<img/>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<img/>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<img/>
```

I am tried to collect IMG elements **look** like this via CSS:

```
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

"Float:left" only moves IMGs to beginning of previous P element.
Without JS, is there any way to collect programmaticly IMG elements like that with CSS? *Or in another way to move P elements to end of document?*

Position:absolute would be a solution ofcource, but then I loose image height that make a image chain that looks like a series..

Comment: Except for `position: absolute` which won't allow placing them underneath each other, not really - you may need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Ye cannae change the laws o' physics Captain!

Comment: I am not trying to change its real order, I just want to change its appearence. Was that why CSS exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your images are sibblings to your paragraphs, you can use Flexbox to do this.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/htJqA

```
.container {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container p {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-flex-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
```

However, this won't work in any IE older than IE10.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Wow!! Thank you! I am not aware of that! I think most of us too!

Answer (score 2):

**YES, it is possible :)**

for the paragraph to be underneath we must give the container the margin-top height of all the elements together, here I used the parent **body**

again, this works. but bad for performance

http://jsfiddle.net/TJU2w/

```
img {
    position:absolute;

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
p { background: grey; }

img:nth-of-type(1){
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
img:nth-of-type(2){
    top: 110px;
    left: 0;
}
img:nth-of-type(3){
    top: 220px;
    left: 0;
}
img:nth-of-type(4){
    top: 330px;
    left: 0;
}
img:nth-of-type(5){
    top: 440px;
    left: 0;
}

body {
    margin-top: 550px;

}
```

Comment: Well, what if there was 4 or 6 images? I need it as fluid. and thank you for answer!

Comment: these only work if that amount of images exist.
as seen here with 6 images http://jsfiddle.net/TJU2w/1/

Comment: and here is with 4 http://jsfiddle.net/TJU2w/2/..

**you would need javascript to adjust the margin-top though** if you require it to be fluid

Comment: Also, remember **css is for visual**, **js is for behaviour**. so detecting measurements is not something css can do.

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript it is not possible to change the hierachy of a document.

What you can do is change all the positions with `position:relative;`, but that is a lot of work and does not work generic.